# IndexError while calling dunder methods

Tags: python, format, index-error

I want to print the values from the dunder methods of a class `foo`. However, I got the error:

```
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

The code snippet is as follows:

```py
class foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Testing'
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Programming'
    
print('{}{}'.format(foo()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template string has two placeholders while you pass only one value in the `.format()` call. `.format()` will only execute `__str__`, not `__repr__`. You should either use

```
print('{}'.format(foo()))
```

or

```
my_foo = foo()
print('{}{}'.format(my_foo, repr(my_foo)))
```

As a side note, class names should be in title case (`Foo`) per PEP-8.

Comment: `!s` is the format modifier for `str()` and `!r` is `repr()`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). Your answer is not correct. You are not instantiating the second one, and also you should have passed a `foo` instance only once, i.e. `.format(foo())` because you only use one placeholder `{0}` in your implementation.

Comment: I have used two placeholders `{0!s}{0!r}` . Isnt it so? @Selcuk

Comment: No, they are the same one because you used an index (`0`).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it gave me the desired output.

```
class foo (object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Testing'
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Programming'
    
print('{0!s}{0!r}'.format(foo(),repr(foo)))
```

Output:

```
TestingProgramming
```